# PHP Image Libraries

Tags: php, image, image-processing, dictionary

I'm working on a PHP application that needs to obtain data from a topographical map (different elevations denoted by different colors). I need to do two things:

1. Using this map (800x600), find a way to determine the exact pixel location of a particular city. For example, San Francisco is located at precisely 121x585.
2. Using the location from (1) above, I need to read the exact color at that location.

Note: The map provider does not provide location-based data, only a colored map. I suspect multiple libraries would be needed to map coordinates to locations on the map (via a ratio?) and then use OCR to read the color.

Are there any PHP libraries/tools that do this? How would you pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the pixel-coordinates, you can use PHP's built-in [GD](http://www.php.net/gd) library to [sample the color](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) of an arbitrary pixel quite easily.

The tricky bit will be determining the pixel to sample, which can get pretty darned tricky.  The earth being sphere-like, maps use various [projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) to produce a 2-d representation.  If you know how the colored map image is projected, and you know the latitude/longitude of the pixel at (0,0), you should be able to write a function to convert lat/long to a pixel coordinate.

Comment: You need the maps scale as well, either that or another point to relate to.

Answer (score 1):

I may not have understood the problem entirely, but you should map the locations you want into an array (of objects?)

```
$city_mapping = array(new City("San Francisco", 121, 585), new City....); //Map your cities to an array.
```

Where `City` should be defined as a class to contain those variables.

---

Then use **[`imagecolorat()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)** to check for the color.

Comment: -1, completely misses the fact that he wants to find the cities automatically.

Comment: It's not possible to determine the points of cities on an annonymouse map, with no relation points to hang on to, and no scale. He has to map the points himself.